# Perform push and pull together in mongodb through mongoose Expresss

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been caught in a situation where I have to perform push and pull together.

I have Schema of categories and posts where Posts can have multiple categories and Categories will have array of multiple posts using Object Referencing method of mongoose like this-

```
    PostSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
      title:{type:String, required:true},
      content:{type:String, required:true}, 
      categories:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Categories'}]     
})
```

Same way I have set up Schema for categories-

```
   CatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name:{type:String, required:true},
      slug:{type:String, required:true}, 
      posts:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Posts'}]     
})
```

Now When I create a post, I push postId in all categories of Categories collection.

But PROBLEM OCCURS when I try to UPDATE POST AND CHOOSE DIFFERENT CATEGORIES from earlier this time.

I can still push updated postId in newly selected categories but How do I pull postId from those categories which are not selected during update but selected during creation. They still store this postId as it was initially pushed.

In clearer, I want to update posts array in categories collection whenever update a category. All types of solutions are welcome including better approach of creating schema or solving this particular problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand that for this update you require postID, arrayOldCaretoryiesID, and arrayNewCategoriesID.

Let's find and remove from the current post the category you need.

```
const deletedCatFromPost = await Post.updateOne({ _id: postID }, { $pull: { categories: arrayOldCaretoryiesID } })
```

Second, remove from old categories by an array of IDs the post you need.

```
const removedOldCategories = await Categories.updateMany({_id:{$or: arrayOldCaretoryiesID }},{ $pull:{ posts: postID }})
```

Finally, add to new categories by an array of IDs a new postID.

```
const addNewCategories = await Categories.updateMany({_id: { $or: arrayNewCategoriesID} },{$push:{ posts: postID }})
```

Hope this can help you.

**Update**:

Second, remove from old categories by an array of IDs the post you need.

```
const removedOldCategories = await Categories.updateMany({_id:{$in: arrayOldCaretoryiesID }},{ $pull:{ posts: postID }})
```

Comment: Thanks for possible solution. Anyways It threw error(`Error: Can't use $or`) while using' `$or`, `$in` solved my problem but still credit is to you for logic.

Comment: I've just tried on my PC and it's working fine. Could you give please more information about the error or give the code that is failing. Thanks.

Comment: Even I didn't get much info about that, all it could err is this tiny message `Error Can't use $or`. And my schema is exactly same as above. All I am trying is taking an array of old and new cats and trying to push and pull in posts array. May be this line of Mongo docs explainsit `$or versus $in

When using $or with <expressions> that are equality checks for the value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or operator.`

Comment: You're right, you should use $in instead of $or. I'll update the answer.